# Accessing MySQL tables from server application

Tags: android, mysql, linux

I am undertaking a project where I am building an android client app that sends requests to a server (Which handles the heavy logic code). This server then grabs the data from my Linux Distro, formats it and relays it on to the client.

Now my sever application will be on a physical server connected to my linux box. The distribution I am using is FreePBX and has a MySQL server set up inside for call logs and all relevant data that I would like to access.

In my server code (Java) do I have to connect to the database in the distro or can I just extrapolate data from the .frm/.MYD/.MYI files that are in /var/lib/mysql/.. ? I am just confused as to how to access the MySQL tables exactly.

I just want to know if there is a universally accepted method for doing this.

After I have this data I plan to put it into XML format and sent it to my client. I was told this is the best way to approach that side of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT ACCESS low level database file by hand. You have to access your table with the right connector using mysql engine query to retrieve /create / update / delete your data. In your case use a Java connector for MySql, that you can find on MySql site.

Using this connector in a java Web Application for example you can expose data to your clients with a RESTful service in Xml / Json format.

There are many many tutorial on how write this kind of architecture. Personally I use Spring MVC + Spring Data + Hibernate on Server Side and Spring Android on client side (I also use Ormlite on client side because of I'm an ORM fan). I also use Jackson library to make serialization / deserialization of my object in json format. But these are my choces.. there are many library, many framework you can use. Now you have a few names on which to search about :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I now know NOT to access the low level files by hand! Could I ask your opinion on one thing? I am considering now having my Android client talk to a PHP script that requests data from my FreePBX MySQL database and this then packages the result as a JSON. I saw it here: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/intro-guide-to-android-client-server-communication/   Would you see this as an easier option to my original idea using a Java server and simple sockets? Note, this is my first big project!

Comment: @user3311578 It could be a point of start! And it take in consideration a complete use case.

Answer (score 0):

.frm/.MYD/.MYI files are used for mysql internally, if you try to modify that files may be mysql server will crash.

But, if you are using Java you must use MySQL Connector/J to make a database connection and open tables, when you are connected to MySQL you can insert data (bulk data also) on tables using regular SQL.

See: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html